# Adding website id to gmail messenger list?

Tags: gmail, web

All,

Is it possible to add a website to gmail messenger list.what ever the purpose may be....

I have seen someone doing this today. If so please guide me to the possible link

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use your own address with the client? Or simply adding like a bookmark to the list? If it is the first, let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> add a website to gmail messenger list

Do you mean to add a contact whose id is `mycoolid@somedomain.com` ? That is possible, if `somedomain.com` uses [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) for their mail & IM needs.